# Wheel conversion to Fixed gear (threaded hub)

Tags: wheels, hub, fixed-gear

I would like to convert a wheel with a threaded hub to fixed gear.

**Here the wheel:**

[image]

**Herer the "fixed gear set":**

[image]

When I mount them together, there is no place to put the lock ring.

Without putting a lock ring, can I use it as a fixed gear?
Any other suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed cog can't be properly installed on your wheel. Hubs intended for use with track cogs have a separate smaller reverse thread for the lockring. The reason for reverse thread is that when you apply reverse torque, it unscrews the cog but tightens the lock ring so that the cog stays in place.

If you absolutely have to use track cog with this hub, there are bottom bracket lockrings that fit the same thread. With thread locking compound and lots of torque it sort of stays in place. This setup is called suicide hub, and it really should not be used except with rear brake and very careful braking.

Comment: I checked there is no enogh place to put a BB lockring. Also what would be the best practice to approach this? To by a suitable wheel? To change hub to a flip flop fixed gear hub?

Comment: You need a flip flop or track hub. Replacing just the hub means rebuilding the wheel with new hub and spokes, reusing only the rim, so the most economical option is probably new wheel.

Comment: Does it exists a 26-inch wheel with flip flop hub? What is the best place to buy it online?

Comment: If I use such hub: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32318458704.html. Do I have to change spokes?

Comment: @MichaelD The hubs need to have exact same hole count, flange offsets and hole circle diameter. There lots of wheelbuilding tutorials around, read them and related questions on this site and decide then decide if you want to try it.